# ESP32 not connecting to MPU9500/6500

Tags: arduino, esp32, mpu

I am currently using a ESP-32s WROOM dev board v1.1 as a control module. I have connected this to a MPU9250/6500 as an IMU, using the following connections:
[image: Diagram of connections between the MPU9500/6500 and ESP32]
As code for the ESP-32s WROOM dev board v1.1 i have used the Arduino IDE 2.2.1 (ALKS ESP32 as board) with the following code:

```
    #include "MPU9250.h"

    // an MPU9250 object with the MPU-9250 sensor on I2C bus 0 with address 0x68
    MPU9250 IMU(Wire, 0x68);
    int status;

    void setup() {
      // serial to display data
      Serial.begin(115200);
      while (!Serial) {}

      // start communication with IMU
      status = IMU.begin();
      if (status < 0) {
        Serial.println("IMU initialization unsuccessful");
        Serial.println("Check IMU wiring or try cycling power");
        Serial.print("Status: ");
        Serial.println(status);
        while (1) {}
      }
    }

    void loop() {
      // read the sensor
      IMU.readSensor();
      // display the data
      Serial.print(IMU.getAccelX_mss(), 6);
      Serial.print("\t");
      Serial.print(IMU.getAccelY_mss(), 6);
      Serial.print("\t");
      Serial.print(IMU.getAccelZ_mss(), 6);
      Serial.print("\t");
      Serial.print(IMU.getGyroX_rads(), 6);
      Serial.print("\t");
      Serial.print(IMU.getGyroY_rads(), 6);
      Serial.print("\t");
      Serial.print(IMU.getGyroZ_rads(), 6);
      Serial.print("\t");
      Serial.print(IMU.getMagX_uT(), 6);
      Serial.print("\t");
      Serial.print(IMU.getMagY_uT(), 6);
      Serial.print("\t");
      Serial.print(IMU.getMagZ_uT(), 6);
      Serial.print("\t");
      Serial.println(IMU.getTemperature_C(), 6);
      delay(100);
    }
```

This is code from the turtorial [here](https://microcontrollerslab.com/esp32-mpu9250-tutorial/) using the metioned library (which I have installed).
Now, when I this code is run on the ESP32, the following result is returned in the Serial Monitor:

```
    IMU initialization unsuccessful
    Check IMU wiring or try cycling power
    Status: -1
```

This is obviously a problem, and this is why i am asking for help. Because if i understand this correctly, the ESP32 can't connect to the MPU9250/6500. (And yes i have checked the wiring is correct)

I tried the following:

- Replace all wires in the circut
- Test all the wires' conductivity
- Replace the wire from the computer to the ESP32
- Use another computer to program the ESP32
- Replace the ESP-32s WROOM dev board v1.1 with a ESP-32S WROOM dev board v1
- Replace the ESP-32s WROOM dev board v1.1 with an Arduino Uno
- Replace the MPU9250/6500
- Many different tutorials, indcluding but not limited to the following: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mzwovYcozvI, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yhz3bRQLvBY, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V4NdsBjUAO0, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dXcF-Uqa-gw
- Crying

Comment: I2C requires pull-up resistors on both signal lines to work.  Do either of the boards have those built-in?

Comment: If you run an I2C Scanner sketch, will it be able to detect the MPU chip at i2c address 0x68?

Comment: @hcheung, Very good idea! I did run a I2C-scanner, and did detect a device at adress 0x68. (scanner taken from https://esp32.com/viewtopic.php?t=4742) Maybe the initialization of the code is wrong?

Comment: @jasonharper, That seems like the case. In the first tutorial [this](https://microcontrollerslab.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/MPU9250-9-DOF-MEMS-Sensor-Module-components-768x518.jpg) diagram is used, which shows two pulll-up resistors. (To be clear, these are also present on my board)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. So it turns out that initializing the I2C-protocol using the `Wire.begin()`, for some reason doesn't use the standard SDA- and SCL-pins. To do that you have to initialize the I2C-communication using the line `Wire.begin(21, 22)`, which sets the SDA- and SCL-pins to 21 and 22.
To implement this you do:

```
TwoWire MainWire = TwoWire(0);
MPU9250 IMU = MPU9250(MainWire, 0x68);
```

in the start of the code. And the following in setup:

```
MainWire.begin(21,22); 
IMU.begin();
```